# cc in php mail not working

Tags: php, email

I am using this code to send a form with uploaded file. However It is working fine with primary mail but do not send cc mail.

```
    $headers = "From: $email";
    $headers .= 'Cc: xyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

    // create a boundary string. It must be unique
      $semi_rand = md5(time());
      $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

      // Add the headers for a file attachment
      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
```

please help me to make it run. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u have to try this way

```
    $headers =  'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" ;
    $headers .= 'Cc: xyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: upvote is locked, if you edit the solution i will do it sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a line feed after the first header line

```
$headers = "From: $email";
$headers .= 'Cc: xyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

This will output `From: $emailCc: xyz@gmail.com` in your header - add a line break on first line

Answer (score 0):

What really worked for me was to create 2 variables "$to" and "$recipients". Inside the $recipients variable you concatenate the $cc variable like this:

```
$recipients = $to . ", " . $cc;

                        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                                          'To' => $to,
                                          'Cc' => $cc,
                                          'Subject' => $subject,
                                          'MIME-Version' => 1,
                                          'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');

$mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $message);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

`CC` in the headers is nice, but it doesn't actually cause it to get sent to the end-user. You need to provide in the `mail()` function in the `$to` value, the addresses of the additional people you want to receive a copy of the email. This includes To, CC and BCC.

There is a very nice CC and BCC example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: This is not correct. The documentation clearly states that Cc and Bcc must be included in the `$additional_headers parameter`