# CC part is not working in php mail function

Tags: php

I have this php code for mail.
Everythings working fine but the CC part is not working

```
$headers = "From:".$from."\r\n"; 
                $headers.= "Cc: dainest7138@gmail.com\r\n";
                $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
                $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
                $headers.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

                mail($to_mail, $subject2, $mess2, $headers);
```

Now the mail is being recieved at the address defined in from. The content and all other things are fine but no mail is being recieved on the address defined in "CC" part.

Please Help me understanding the problem.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cc in php mail not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241624/cc-in-php-mail-not-working)

Comment: @ManthanDave. i have already tried the solution in the problem you mentioned. But that didn't work out.

Comment: have you check your spam folder ? also confirm that if any error shows there ?

Comment: You need to manually send the email to everybody in the CC list.

Comment: @ManthanDave. Yes. I did check the spam folder too. but still couldn't find the mails. its working fine for the "To" address , the problems only with "Cc"

Comment: @Rishav. Can't it be done from the code here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";


            $headers .= 'From:'.$from. "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Cc: dainest7138@gmail.com' . "\r\n";


            mail($to_mail, $subject2, $mess2, $headers);
```

Re-edited it. Try this one.

Comment: Sorry but still not working. Does it have to do something with the configurations?

Comment: no. the mail is being recieved at the address defined in "To". the "form" part is also fine. the problem is just that i am not able to recieve the mail on the address in "\Cc"